# I need to run headless browser on ec2 using selenium python. I tried chrome headless but it didn't work

Tags: python, selenium, headless-browser

```
import chromedriver   
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options=options)
```

I get the following error when I execute this code:

```
raise RuntimeError('This package supports only Linux, MacOSX or Windows platforms')
RuntimeError: This package supports only Linux, MacOSX or Windows platforms
```

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux AMI?

Answer (score 2):

Okie seems like they have a bug in installation of module

It will only work when you are running under a virtual environment and not when you are using direct system pip installation. The issue occurs because for direct install the drivers are download to `/usr/local` and it expects them to be available at the package location.

Also you have an error in your usage

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options=options)
```

should be

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver.CHROMEDRV_PATH,chrome_options=options)
```

So you can either use virtual env. Or you can just install package and don't import it.

So your code would be

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Tried but it didn't work :(  can we use some other headless browser for Yython apart from Phantomjs? I need to render emails in Linux environment

Comment: I hope you have chrome installed ? and what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Yes I have chrome installed   Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Download this file manually `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.32/chromedriver_linux64.zip` and unzip it to `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure to `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver` after that